# Getting around lack of Java generics at runtime, bind a super type to a subclass instance

Tags: java, generics, binding

Imagine a method such as

```
public <F extends Fruit> Juice<F> makeJuiceFrom(Collection<F> fruits) {
    for (F fruit: fruits) {
        handleFruit(fruit);
    }
    return ...
}
```

Now I want to overload the handleFruit method such that it handles different types of fruit e.g.

```
 void handleFruit(Apple),  void handleFruit(Orange)
```

where orange and apple extend Fruit.

However, right now I am of course forced to right a method to hard code binding:

```
private void HandleFruit(Fruit fruit) {
if (Fruit instanceof Apple)
 handleFruit(((Apple)fruit));
else if (...)
```

...
    }

Is there any way I can dynamically bind it:

```
private void handleFruit(Fruit fruit) {
    handleFruit(((fruit.getType)fruit));
}
```

Comment: What about making it a method of  the `Fruit` class and using polymorphism?

Comment: Arguments are resolved at compile time, so what you want to do isn't possible in Java. Either do what @kraskevich says or use the visitor pattern.

Comment: Note that the keyword you are looking for is _multiple dispatch_. Wikipedia and SO have a number of pages about it and how it relates to Java.

Comment: @kraskevich Only viable if there is just one implementation of `JuiceMaker` so you don't need to dynamically dispatch on that side. Otherwise this is double dispatch and calls for the infamously verbose and complex Visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for the [**visitor pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Write a method in each subclass of `Fruit`:

```
public void visit(Juice j) {
    j.handleFruit(this);
}
```

Now, you can have different types of `handleFruit()`, and the static type of `this` is specific (`Apple`/`Orange`/...) according to the implementing class of the `visit()` method, and the correct method will be called.

Invoke with `fruit.visit(this)` from your `Juice` class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add the method to `Fruit` and call it thus

```
interface Fruit {
    handleFruit();
}

public <F extends Fruit> Juice<F> makeJuiceFrom(Collection<F> fruits) {
    for (Fruit fruit: fruits) {
        fruit.handleFruit();
    }
    return ...
}
```

Comment: But suppose `handleFruit()` has a dependency on `JuiceMaker` (after all, it is currently in that class), then it would work only if `JuiceMaker` was a single implementation.